# Why gettext() in selenium is returning a-singlespace-b instead of a-multiplespaces-b?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am testing TodoMVC page's todo list and I came across a problem where in the DOM label tag of the element is having a text with many spaces between two letters, but on the UI it is showing letter single space then another letter, and when gettext() is performed on the element we are getting "a b" which is visible on the UI instead of the text present in label tag of that element.

[image: Refer this image for clarity of the problem]

Comment: Maybe the actual <input> element has some client side formatting on it?

Comment: so the gettext() checks for text on the UI instead of the text present inside that web element?

Comment: getText(); will return the innerText of a WebElement object. [It also will remove all leading and trailing whitespace](http://makeseleniumeasy.com/2017/07/17/all-about-gettext-method-what-why-and-how/). To me it seems like that particular WebElement you are looking at has some kind of formatting on the client side that separates Strings by 1 space maximum. Edit: Unless the amount of whitespace is crucual to the validation you are doing, just remove all spaces with `yourString.replace(" ","");` and then validate the actual text is as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how Selenium WebDriver works. Since it designed for UI testing, all interactions with Browser data are made from a user perspective.

Here is an extraction from [Get Element Text W3C specification](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#get-element-text):

> NOTE
>   The Get Element Text command intends to return an element’s text “as rendered”. An element’s rendered text is also used for locating **a** elements by their link text and partial link text.
>
> One of the major inputs to this specification was the open source Selenium project. This was in wide-spread use before this specification written, and so had set user expectations of how the Get Element Text command should work. As such, the approach presented here is known to be flawed, but provides the best compatibility with existing users.